# Netbeans Gui Builder hiding tabs

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, authorization

I try to design swing gui in Netbeans. I want to hide some of tabs according to role of user, for example role 1 see tab1,and tab2;  role 2 see tab2 and tab3. I try to this with editing initComponents but it is not possible. What is the solution for this situation? any advice?

Comment: You should still have access to the components created by `initComponents`, depending on how you named them in the form editor.  You simply need to interact with the components as you normally would if you had created the UI by hand...

Comment: i copied to initComponents and rename it Myinit then now it is editible. So if user1 come with role 1, i remove tab3 in this method. i dont know what is the best practice but  it works.

Comment: You'll end not being able to to modify the UI later with the form editor.  Instead, you should simply make your modifications after the `initComponents` method - IMHO

Comment: thank you very much for your support. I'm new in swing, i understood you, but i think not completely. But i dont want some of components on the frame according to user. Now i comment to   //jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel1); in initComponets ( myİnitcomponents ) then i write checkUserRight(String role) method. if role1 come i'll add this role's tab, if another role come i'll add this role's tabs.

Comment: Yep. All I'm saying is you don't need to do it inside the initComponents method, which is normally called within the constructor. Call the initComponents method as per normal, are you call it, remove the tabs you don't want, just like you did with your modified method. This allows you to keep the form capabilities and is the typical mechanism employed with NetBeans form editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a jTabbedPane that will contain all the tabs that you want.

In order to remove a tab:

`jTabbedPane1.remove(jPanel1);`

In order to add a new tab:

`jTabbedPane1.add(jPanel1);`